# $\Sigma_k^\text{P}$−SAT definition is not clear to me

Tags: definition, computational-complexity, quantifiers, satisfiability

I don't understand if by saying there are $k$ alternating quantifiers on the variables $x_1$,$x_2$...$x_k$, It means we quantify ALL variables (there are only $k$ variables in the SAT formula) or just $k$ of them (so there can be more than $k$ variables) 
For example, for $\Sigma_1^\text{P}$-SAT, the clause has to be with only one variable who is quantified?
It seems like there have to be some free variables left (not under quantifiers) but I'm not sure. (I know TQBF demands no free variables.)
Thanks.

Comment: You always quantify all variables, otherwise the formula doesn't have a truth value.
I think in this case it means you have k alterations, so you can have more than k variables but it goes Exists x1,x2 ForAll x3,x4,x5 Exists.... and so on.
An exact definition of a link to one would help.

Comment: @gil_bz: I don't really remember but isn't the following formula TRUE?   $\exists x_1 x_1 OR x_2 OR x_3$

Comment: @gil_bz: Because if x1=1, then for x2=somethign and x3=something the value of the clause is T. I can't recall if the expression I wrote before is well defined (and is T) or it's not well defined. https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8zikqs5pk4o2rk/lesson06.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There are no unquantified variables in SAT.  If no quantifiers are explicitly given, the variables default to being existentially quantified.

When $k$ alternations is spoken of in reference to quantified boolean formulas, it refers to the number of *groups* of variables quantified by $\exists$ or $\forall$, not the number of variables themselves.  So for $\Sigma_1^\text{P}$-SAT there is one group of quantified variables, not one variable.